# Compare start time and end time in list json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json such as:

```
var availabilitys = [
{
  "date": "2015-08-15",
  "timeslots": [
  {
    "id": 52,
    "date": "2015-08-15",
    "start_time": "2015-08-15T10:00:50.836Z",
    "end_time": "2015-08-15T09:00:50.837Z"
  }
  ]
},
{
  "date": "2015-08-16",
  "timeslots": [
  {
    "id": 53,
    "date": "2015-08-16",
    "start_time": "2015-08-16T06:00:00.885Z",
    "end_time": "2015-08-16T08:00:00.885Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 72,
    "date": "2015-08-16",
    "start_time": "2015-08-16T07:00:00.885Z",
    "end_time": "2015-08-16T08:00:00.885Z"
  }
  ]
},
{
  "date": "2015-08-17",
  "timeslots": [
  {
    "id": 54,
    "date": "2015-08-17",
    "start_time": "2015-08-17T11:25:50.893Z",
    "end_time": "2015-08-17T10:25:50.893Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "date": "2015-08-17",
    "start_time": "2015-08-17T11:25:50.893Z",
    "end_time": "2015-08-17T10:25:50.893Z"
  }
  ]
}
```

];

I would like to check start and end time of timeslots.
- Start time less than end time in a timeslot
- In a day Start time of a next timeslot must to greater than or equal end time prev timeslot

Hope everybody help me, thanks.

Comment: Is the goal just to validate the data?  (That start times are always before end times and that time slots do no overlap?)

Comment: Yes, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple function that takes in your `availabilitys` array and returns a `Boolean`: `true` if the two conditions (start times before end times and non-overlapping slots) are met for all timeslots, `false` otherwise.

`validateAvailabilities(availabilitys)` correctly returns `false` for your example `availabilitys` array.

```
function validateAvailabilities(avails) {
    return avails.every(dayValidates);

    function dayValidates(day) {
        return day.timeslots.every(startBeforeEnd) &&
               day.timeslots.every(timeslotsDontOverlap);

        function startBeforeEnd(timeslot) {
            return toTime(timeslot.start_time) <= toTime(timeslot.end_time);
        }

        function timeslotsDontOverlap(slot, i, slots) {
            // A timeslot does not overlap if its the first one, or its start time
            // is on or after the previous slot's end time.
            return i === 0 ||
                   toTime(slot.start_time) >= toTime(slots[i - 1].end_time);
        }

        function toTime(dateStr) {
            return new Date(dateStr).getTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: it assumes that the timeslots array for each day are already sorted in ascending order by time.  If this is not the case, it will get the overlapping time slot check wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
(new Date(isoDateStr)).getTime()
```

[gives you a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Please let us know if you will need an advice of how to write comparison of two numbers in JS.

Comment: I have a number, so I would like to compare in loop. I can compare start time and end time. But I can't compare time slots do not overlap in a day( time slot > 1,Start time of a next timeslot must to greater than or equal end time prev timeslot). Please give me a function to validate it, thanks